# How to get words from a text file to a singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, text-files

The object of this assignment is to output a list of words from a file into a singly linked list and then sort them into alphabetical order.  However I cannot figure out how to get the individual words into the linked list.  I am very new at this and any tips or hints would be very appreciated.

Here is my `Node` class which I believe is correct:

```
//Node of a singly linked list of strings
public class Node {
   private String element;
   private Node next;

   //creates a node with the given element and next

   public Node(String s, Node n){
      element = s;
      next = n;
   }

   //Returns the elements of this
   public String getElement(){
      return element;
   }
   public Node getNext(){
      return next;
   }

   //Modifier
   //Sets the element of this
   public void setElement(String newElement){
      element = newElement;
   }

   //Sets the next node of this
   public void setNext(Node newNext){
      next = newNext;
   }
}
```

Here is my main class where takes the sentences from a file and breaks it down to individual words.  That is were I have a problem I can't figure out how to get the individuals words into a linked list:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class DictionaryTester{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input1"));
      String file;
      int lineNum = 1;
      while ((file = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print( "(" + lineNum++ + ") ");
        System.out.println(file.toLowerCase());

        String line = br.readLine();
        //String is split or removes the spaces and places into the array words
        String[] words = line.split(" ");

        //for loop to keep running on the length of the array
        for(int i =0; i< words.length; i++){
          //word is equal to a particular indexed spot of the word array and gets rid of all non-alphabet letters
          String word = words[i];
          word = word.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
      System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Another class I have is `SLinkedList` which would hold the words into the list but like I said I can not figure out how to get the individual words into the list:

```
//Singly linked list
public class SLinkedList {
   //head node of the list
   protected Node head;

   //number of nodes in the list
   protected long size;

   //Default constructor that creates an empty list
   public SLinkedList(){
      head = null;
      size = 0;
   }
}
```

I know how to insert elements of the singly linked list, but trying to get words into list has proven to be difficult for me.  Anything would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

> The scanner can also use delimiters other than whitespace. This
>   example reads several items in from a string:
>
> ```
>  String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
>  Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
>  System.out.println(s.nextInt());
>  System.out.println(s.nextInt());
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  System.out.println(s.next());
>  s.close();
> ```

Loop until the end of the file, cache the current word, and insert it in the current Node. Then move to the next Node in the link, and repeat.

Once you've finished, you'll have to do some sort of sort and swapping about of the Nodes.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I need to input a file consisting of the sentences, I cannot use a Scanner

Answer (score 0):

Try this One, Hope this will be usefull for you...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileLinkList
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
String content = new String();
int count=1;
File file = new File("abc.txt");
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

 try {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
content = sc.nextLine();
list.add(content);
}
sc.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
fnf.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
}

Collections.reverse(list);
Iterator i = list.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
System.out.print("Node " + (count++) + " : ");
System.out.println(i.next());
}
 }
 }
```